# How do I Combine rows based on a key with values combined in a single column

Tags: r

I tried different approaches but what i need to do is to combine the values of a column of different rows into a single row with one column. I know that it's not normalized data, but it's simpler to understand this way.

#### What I've tried:

##### Dataset

```
#dataset
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      id   key value
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1     1 h    
 2     2     1 e    
 3     3     1 l    
 4     4     1 l    
 5     5     1 o    
 6     6     2 w    
 7     7     2 o    
 8     8     2 r    
 9     9     2 l    
10    10     2 d
```

```
test <- tribble(~id, ~key, ~value,
                1, 1, "h",
                2, 1, "e",
                3, 1, "l",
                4, 1, "l",
                5, 1, "o",
                6, 2, "w",
                7, 2, "o",
                8, 2, "r",
                9, 2, "l",
                10,2, "d")

# pivot_wider() doesnt work
result <- test %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = "key", values_from = "value")
```

#### What I need

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    key value    
  <dbl> <list>   
1     1 <chr [5]>
2     2 <chr [5]>
```

```
expected <- tribble(~key, ~value,
                    1, c("h", "e", "l", "l","o"),
                    2, c("w", "o", "r", "l", "d"))
```

order doesn't matter but i do need to have them in the same column

```
expected <- tribble(~key, ~value,
                    1, c("e", "l", "l", "h","o"),
                    2, c("r", "o", "d", "l", "w"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `tidyr::nest_by()`

```r
library(tidyverse)
test <- tribble(~id, ~key, ~value,
                1, 1, "h",
                2, 1, "e",
                3, 1, "l",
                4, 1, "l",
                5, 1, "o",
                6, 2, "w",
                7, 2, "o",
                8, 2, "r",
                9, 2, "l",
                10,2, "d")

test %>% select(-id) %>% nest_by(key)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Rowwise:  key
#>     key               data
#>   <dbl> <list<tibble[,1]>>
#> 1     1            [5 x 1]
#> 2     2            [5 x 1]
```

---

or simply in dplyr

```r
test %>% group_by(key) %>%
  summarise(value = list(value))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>     key value    
#>   <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     1 <chr [5]>
#> 2     2 <chr [5]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>